# Good IDE for Corona SDK on OSX?

Tags: macos, ide, lua, intellij-idea, coronasdk

Just started with Corona SDK and could not find any IDE with proper Corona SDK integration. Can someone list down some good IDEs for working with Corona SDK on OSX.

Here's what I've tried:

1. BBEdit: and its really cool (has autocomplete and fairly nice
   syntax highlighting) but its a text editor and not exactly an IDE. I
   can't see all the non lua files (like .png files), lack of
   integrated terminal and debugger etc.
2. Textmate : The visually "most complete" solution I could find for Mac, as of solutions available right now. Its snippets and pseudo-autocomplete are right now the best I could find. Am using this one as my IDE. But would really appreciate something more where basic things like split-views are supported.
3. IntelliJ IDEA (community edition) : Superb IDE if only I could figure out how to
   configure for corona simulator on OSX. It works perfect for Windows
   Corona SDK but sadly, for OSX, no such luck.
4. Eclipse ... yikes!!. Never really liked that IDE (a personal
   dislike from some Perl projects where it just wont locate some
   specific Perl libraries properly.. that's really a discussion for
   another day) but again its latest version does not seem to have
   Corona SDK support.

Does anyone have any idea/suggestions. Also, any tips to make Corona SDK work with IntelliJ IDEA (on OSX) will be most welcome.

Comment: if someone downvoted this, please give the reasons.

Comment: Some people thing that subjective questions like what is the "best" tool for something are too vague for SO. Its safest to stick to objective questions that will have a single well defined answer :(

Comment: I see, have edited the question.

Comment: In the end, settled for Lua Glider. Though not fully refined, still looked like the best one among available options. Perhaps Textmate and Lua Glider are the only two decent alternatives available on OSX.

Answer (score 2):

Shameless plug, but you may try [ZeroBrane Studio](http://studio.zerobrane.com). Starting from the version 0.34 it includes Corona debugging and auto-complete support. Some people [have used it on OSX](https://github.com/pkulchenko/ZeroBraneStudio/issues/73) and have been happy with it. <s>Keep in mind that debugging support for Corona is limited on OSX due to constraints in the Corona Simulator (no `loadstring` support which prevents remote console and watches from working).</s> ZeroBrane Studio v0.361 and later includes full support for OSX debugging.